# MissingPropertyException in gradle android

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I am creating some constants in my build gradle file and I am getting the following error while building

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'App'.
```

> Exception evaluating property 'gradle' for java.util.ArrayList, Reason:
> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: gradle for class: java.lang.String

This is my top level gradle where I am making th change

```
buildscript {
ext{
    compileSdkVersion = 31
    targetSdkVersion = 31
    minSdkVersion = 21
    versions=[
            kotlin='1.6.10',
            gradle='4.2.1'
    ]

}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()

}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:${versions.gradle}"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${versions.kotlin}"
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I have this issue while trying to import a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was syntax Issue caused due to the use of `=`

```
versions = [
            kotlin : '1.6.10',
            gradlePlugin : '4.2.1'
    ]
```